Changes applied to Group Policies keeps reverting after Reboot
When I logged up on my PC the Lock screen suddenly requires CTRL+ALT+DEL to show login screen, this happen after I was installing 3rd party Antivirus. Even after I uninstalled the AV the Lock screen behavior still present.  I thought the AV has been messed up some of GPO/SecPol Object. So I checked the "Interactive logon: Do not require CTRL+ALT+DEL" policy I change it to "Enabled". When I'm sign off and log on again the message "Press CTRL+ALT+DEL to unlock" is dissapeared.
But when I Reboot the Windows the message appeared again and then when I'm checked the SecPol in "Local Policies/Security Options/Interactive logon: Do not require CTRL+ALT+DEL" it changes back to "Disabled".
I've struggled with this problem for past month I was thinking to just do fresh install Windows, but I can't do that for now. I'm asking here to seek for help to troubleshoot of this problem.
